Fisheye to equirectangular
I struggle to understand conversion from fisheye to equirectangular based on https://paulbourke.net/dome/dualfish2sphere/.
The first step of taken fisheye image coordinates $x$ and $y$ and tarnsforming that to $\phi$ and $\theta$ is clear to me. But what about transforming this to longitude and latitude? The formulae presented use $P_{x,y,z}$ to transform from $\phi$ and $\theta$ to longitude and latitude... But yeah, $P_{x,y,z}$ are defined based on longitude and latitude.
Can someone please elaborate on these definitions from 3D vector to longitude/latitude step? Any additional resources are also appreciated, my math background has mostly been forgotten.

